# Does SignTool produce certificates using X509?

Tags: c#, windows, cryptography, x509, signtool

Does SignTool use X.509?

Could I extract and verify a digital signature from SignTool using the X509 functions in `C#`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It seems to generate "PKCS#7" files, also known as the Cryptographic Message Syntax. Those more or less exclusively use X.509. Almost all PKI operations performed by Microsoft are based on X.509 compatible PKI.

And yes, there seem to be a .NET API  specified for this in the [`System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180945%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).